# thread sync with pthread conditional variable

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I am experiencing some problems with thread synchronization using pthread conditional variable. I have one thread that parses messages extracting some values and another thread that increments some variables using the extracted values. 
I used pthread conditional variable to synchronize these two threads.
The first thread looks like the snippet below:

```
if(parse_ok){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&q_mutex);
  q = extract_value();
  q_changed = true;
  printf("...awake\n");
  pthread_cond_signal(&q_cond_var);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&q_mutex);
 }
```

The worker thread looks like the snippet below:

```
while(true){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&q_mutex);                              
  if( !q_changed ){
    std::cout<<"waiting..!"<<std::endl;
    pthread_cond_wait(&q_cond_var, &q_mutex);
  }                                                      
  if(q_changed){
     q_changed = false;
    _actual_q += q;
    _total_q += q;
    _quant_q += q/_fixed_quantity;
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&q_mutex);
}//END of while TRUE
```

This code works correctly most of time.
Sometimes happens, when I receive a lot of messages, one after the other, that the sleeping thread skips some awakening. May I need some semaphore to block receiving thread until the working thread completes its work? How?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: May want to make q_changed *volatile*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your code is written, there's no *guarantee* that the second worker thread will process the new input *every time* the first thread signals it. You can extend the use the `q_changed` variable, however, to ensure that this happens.

Change your first thread to this:

```
if(parse_ok){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&q_mutex);
    while (q_changed) // Always wait in in loop
        pthread_cond_wait(&q_cond_var, &q_mutex);
    q = extract_value();
    q_changed = true;
    pthread_cond_signal(&q_cond_var);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&q_mutex);
}
```

And change your second, worker thread to this:

```
while(true){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&q_mutex);
    while( !q_changed ) // Always wait in a loop
        pthread_cond_wait(&q_cond_var, &q_mutex);
    q_changed = false;
    _actual_q += q;
    _total_q += q;
    _quant_q += q/_fixed_quantity;
    pthread_cond_signal(&q_cond_var);     
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&q_mutex);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several things potentially biting you here:

a) printf and cout are not threadsafe, thus their output might not reflect the actual order of the waiting and waking in the code.

b) spurious wakeups aren't handled efficiently in your code.  I'd change the `if(  !q_changed )` conditional to `while (!q_changed)` to minimize the amount of time you take to re-wait on the condition variable if spuriously awoken (this will also allow you to remove the last `if (q_changed)` conditional block).

EDIT (based on comments by @EOF et al): If using a modern C++/C implementation (I assume you're not since you're using pthreads), then it is most likely that b) is your problem.  The race in this case is that waiting thread can wake then unlock the mutex. In the meantime the signaling thread acquires the lock and signals.  Since you weren't waiting on the condition, you didn't get the signal. Note however, that it's not a problem - you still process the data - it's just that you didn't output a 'waiting' message to cout in this case.

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *7.21.2 Streams 7 Each stream has an associated lock that is used to prevent data races when multiple
threads of execution access a stream, and to restrict the interleaving of stream operations
performed by multiple threads. Only one thread may hold this lock at a time. The lock is
reentrant: a single thread may hold the lock multiple times at a given time.* `printf()` *is* threadsafe.

Comment: @EOF You forget that C++11 and C++14 incorporate *C99*, only with C++17 will *C11* be the incorporated C version. So rules based on C11 are irrelevant. (for completeness, C++98/03 incorporated C89).

Comment: @JesperJuhl 1) The question is tagged C as well as C++. 2) In that case, *none* of the C functions are threadsafe in C++, since there *are* no threads in C prior to C11.

Comment: @EOF 1) I overlooked that. 2) Indeed.